# VPN connection failed with error nm-applet-CRITICAL **: get_menu_item_for_ap: assertion 'dup_data.hash != NULL' failed

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 I failing to access my vpn as I don't receive the box for entering the password 
The syslog has the following error:

```
nm-applet-CRITICAL **: get_menu_item_for_ap: assertion 'dup_data.hash != NULL' failed
```

i restarted the NM few times with no chance !
any clue of workaround ?

Comment: Have you tried using OpenVPN? Hide-Me has a very nice tutorial on this.

Comment: it is not supported for this type of vpn - the server is l2tp - not supported by open-vpn